# How to run Jakarta EE application with embedded server?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish, wildfly, h2

My goal is to create Jakarta EE web application which uses embedded web server and embedded database, so it will be possible to run this webapp with single command.

Currently I have an app which uses embedded H2 database, it works fine when deployed to separate Glassfish instance, but fails with embedded one.

I have tried both `cargo-maven3-plugin` and `wildfly-maven-plugin`.

### Sample project

This is web app I'm trying to launch in embedded Jakarta EE server:

`./pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakartaee-hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>jakartaee-hello-world</name>
    <description>
    </description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.report.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.report.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <jakartaee-api.version>10.0.0</jakartaee-api.version>
        <payara.version>6.2023.5</payara.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <war-plugin.version>3.3.2</war-plugin.version>
        <cargo.version>1.10.7</cargo.version>
        <wildfly.version>27.0.1.Final</wildfly.version>
        <wildfly-plugin.version>4.1.0.Final</wildfly-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>myapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Execute 'mvn clean package cargo:run' to run the application. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cargo.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>payara</containerId>
                        <artifactInstaller>
                            <groupId>fish.payara.distributions</groupId>
                            <artifactId>payara</artifactId>
                            <version>${payara.version}</version>
                        </artifactInstaller>
                    </container>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Execute 'mvn clean package wildfly:dev' to run the application. -->
            <!-- It doesn't work for some reason in this Jakarta MVC project -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${wildfly-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>${wildfly.version}</version>
                    <server-config>glassfish-resources.xml</server-config>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\glassfish-resources.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool 
                datasource-classname="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
                name="embeddedConnPool"
                res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">

        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:h2:mem:dataSource;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false" />
        <property name="User" value="root" />
        <property name="Password" value="qwerty" />

    </jdbc-connection-pool>

    <jdbc-resource jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/embeddedDS" pool-name="embeddedConnPool" enabled="true" />
</resources>
```

`src\main\resources\META-INF\persistence.xml`:

```xml
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd" 
    version="3.0">
    
    <persistence-unit   name="only-unit"
                        transaction-type="JTA" >
        
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/embeddedDS</jta-data-source>
        
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    
</persistence>
```

`src\main\java\myapp\rest\DemoApplication.java`:

```java
package myapp.rest;

import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest/*")
public class DemoApplication extends Application {
}
```

`src\main\java\myapp\rest\PersonResource.java`:

```java
package myapp.rest;

import java.util.List;

import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import myapp.dao.PersonDao;
import myapp.model.Person;

@Path("person")
public class PersonResource {

    @Inject
    PersonDao personDao;

    @GET
    @Path("all")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public List<Person> findAll() {
        var list = personDao.findAll();
        return list;
    }
    @POST
    @Path("new")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person create(Person person) {
        person.setId(null);
        System.out.println(person);
        personDao.create(person);
        return person;
    }
}
```

`src\main\java\myapp\dao\PersonDao.java`:

```java
package myapp.dao;

import java.util.List;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import myapp.model.Person;

@ApplicationScoped
public class PersonDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "only-unit")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public Person create(Person person) {
        em.persist(person);
        return person;
    }

    public List<Person> findAll() {
        String queryString = "SELECT p FROM Person p";
        var query = em.createQuery(queryString, Person.class);
        var resultList = query.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }

}
```

`src\main\java\myapp\model\Person.java`:

```java
package myapp.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    
}
```

### Expectations

I was expecting to execute `mvn clean package cargo:run` or `mvn clean package wildfly:dev`, and rest endpoint will become available: `curl.exe -X GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/person/all/`

### Reality

`mvn clean package cargo:run` results in this stacktrace:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Payara 6.2023.5 starting...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] WARNING: You are running the product on an unsupported JDK version and might see unexpected results or exceptions.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Attempting to start cargo-domain.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Payara 6.2023.5 is stopping...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Payara 6.2023.5 is stopped
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: At least one GlassFish deployment has failed: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: GlassFish admin command with args (--interactive=false --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile C:\JAVA2023\JakartaPlatformHiberRestTinyH2\target\cargo\configurations\payara\password.properties deploy --force --contextroot myapp C:\JAVA2023\JakartaPlatformHiberRestTinyH2\target\myapp.war) failed: asadmin exited 1: remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : org/hibernate/bytecode/enhance/spi/EnhancementContextWrapper. Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy failed.
[ERROR] Starting container [org.codehaus.cargo.container.payara.PayaraInstalledLocalContainer@3c6bd624] failed
org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: At least one GlassFish deployment has failed: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: GlassFish admin command with args (--interactive=false --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin --passwordfile C:\JAVA2023\JakartaPlatformHiberRestTinyH2\target\cargo\configurations\payara\password.properties deploy --force --contextroot myapp C:\JAVA2023\JakartaPlatformHiberRestTinyH2\target\myapp.war) failed: asadmin exited 1: remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : org/hibernate/bytecode/enhance/spi/EnhancementContextWrapper. Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy failed.
```

And `mvn clean package wildfly:dev` results in this:

```
[INFO] STANDALONE server is starting up.
13:34:48,329 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 2.0.3.Final
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0214: Could not load configuration file: glassfish-resources.xml. The configuration file argument must specify the path to a file located in the configuration directory. The path must be a relative path, and must be relative to the configuration directory C:\JAVA2023\JakartaPlatformHiberRestTinyH2\target\server\standalone\configuration.
        at org.jboss.as.controller@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.determineMainFile(ConfigurationFile.java:387)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.<init>(ConfigurationFile.java:207)
        at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerEnvironment.<init>(ServerEnvironment.java:590)
        at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:425)
        at org.jboss.as.server@19.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:97)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:353)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:321)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:604)
13:34:48,687 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0239: Aborting with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have a look at the bootable JAR https://docs.wildfly.org/bootablejar/

Comment: @james that's 2000+ lines of text for such a simple task. I've tried executing `mvn clean package org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-jar-maven-plugin:10.0.0.Final:package org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-jar-maven-plugin:10.0.0.Final:run` but got `No valid provisioning configuration, you must set a feature-pack-location, a list of feature-packs or use a provisioning.xml file`.

Comment: Isn't most documentation :) In [there](https://docs.wildfly.org/bootablejar/#wildfly_jar_composing_custom_server_galleon_version) it talks about the feature-pack-location and how to define it in the configuration. You don't need the resteasy-feature-pack, but [here](https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy-examples/blob/d74bf13eef5c8ff8451384bc263e11e0f538ff16/bootable-jar/pom.xml#L109-L168) is an example configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided sample application can be run with this single command:

```
mvn clean package org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven3-plugin:run -Dcargo.maven.containerId=glassfish7x
```

All plugins from `pom.xml` can be removed, apart from `maven-compiler-plugin` and `maven-war-plugin`. No additional configuration is needed.

In console, there will be message:

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] GlassFish 7.0.6 started on port [8080]
[INFO] Press Ctrl-C to stop the container...
```

But pressing Ctrl-C can result in failed attempt of stopping the container - you will have to kill java process manually.

To stop container more properly, first send web-request to server:

```
curl.exe -X GET http://localhost:4848/__asadmin/stop-domain -u admin:adminadmin
```

After that press Ctrl+C, all resources will be released and container will stop properly.

Other containers and usecases available in Codehaus Cargo Maven 3 Plugin can be found here:
https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven+3+Plugin.html

Comment: Hi, I see that you made it work, @Podbrushkin. I just want to add that this way, you still run your app with a standard GlassFish server, it's just automatically started with your application from the single maven command. You can also run your application using GlassFish Embedded, using the GlassFish Embedded maven plugin. It's not much documented, but it's used by GlassFish in its own test suite. For example here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/blob/master/appserver/tests/embedded/maven-plugin/applicationDispatcher/pom.xml#L37.

Comment: For using the GlassFish Embedded maven plugin, you just need to add glassfish-embedded-all dependency and configure the plugin to run the start and deploy commands

Comment: The difference is that, while cargo plugin will start a full GlassFish server in a separate process, GlassFish Embedded maven plugin will start GlassFish Embedded (a stripped down version of GlassFish without admin console, etc.) in the same Java process, so Ctrl+C would naturally stop it without issues.

Comment: @OndroMih I've tried this plugin earlier and tried it now once again, and failed once again. I'm not familiar with configuring plugin commands. Adding it to pom and executing `mvn clean package embedded-glassfish:run embedded-glassfish:deploy` or `embedded-glassfish:start` doesn't work. It gives `The SSL certificate has expired` exceptions, `Undefined Product Name` errors, anything but a working rest endpoint. Maybe you will clarify what exactly needs to be added to pom and what command should be executed next? rn it looks like it needs much more config to run than regular gf, which is weird.